# The following code is running through python IDE but not from CMD or by direct execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pyautogui, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import time

webbrowser.open("https://meet.google.com/huq-etkk-pwv",new=0,autoraise=True)

#auto_input
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','d')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','e')
time.sleep(2)
#custom coordinates are adviced
#coordinates work on standard chrome window with 1920*1080 screen size 16:9 ratio
pyautogui.click(972,428)
```

When i run this via CMD i get an error in the module pyautogui with Tk() name not defined and when i try to execute this directly it just opens a window of CMD and then stops and does nothing but works perfectly when i run it via the Python IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on my Kubuntu (18.04.) 
Which IDE do you use? Is it possible, that it by default runs a different version of python than your CMD (e.g. 3.7 in the IDE and 2.7 in the CMD)?

P.S.
would have posted it in a comment but lack the reputation